# Need to configure my xorg.conf file

Tags: linux, display, xorg, ubuntu-20.04, display-driver

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my pc but ubuntu is not able to configure my display/graphics drivers automatically and that is causing white horizontal lines, that move all over screen. I have intel pentium g630 and 4 gb ram. I need help to configure xorg.conf
[Video the of error](https://youtu.be/GcAXAicoZqY)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A. The Community user is a bot that doesn't read anything. B. English is the language used on SuperUser. C. There is no need for any personal attacks or profanity. Please review https://superuser.com/help/behavior. In addition, Community bot is right. What specifically do you need help with? There are tons of tutorials available on how to edit text files on Linux. Or do you need pointers on what to change? Because in that case, your question doesn't have nearly enough info for anyone to _magically_ solve your problem. Post your xorg.conf, any xorg logs and things that you tried yourself.

Comment: I wonder if your video card does not have enough memory for the resolution you are trying to run at.

Comment: @mtak i have posted the video of the error... and because 'nomodeset' does not show any such errors i think the issue is in graphics driver configuration.....

Comment: @Bib does ubuntu 20.04 uses more memory than windows 10 home 64-bit????... because windows 10 works fine.. I have tried installing ubuntu 14 and ubuntu 18 also..they also show same issue